# While using https request in node js, why chaining functions is not working?

Tags: node.js, express, https, http-post

```
https.request(url, options, (response) => {
  response.on("data", (data) => {
    console.log(JSON.parse(data));
  });
}).write(jsonData).end();
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHER8.png

This is the snippet of nodejs doc.

Comment: please provide the actual error message so others have a better time helping you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.